# Can we make the Dirac representation a gauge theory?

Tags: gauge-theory, field-theory, dirac-equation, gauge-invariance, dirac-matrices

I'm looking for comments and references about an idea :  gauging the Dirac representation of the Dirac matrices.  What kind of field interaction would it give ?

Specifically, the Dirac equation is defined as this (free field, to begin with) :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\gamma^a \; \partial_a \Psi + i \, m \, \Psi = 0.
\end{equation}
By definition, the gamma matrices obeys the following relation :
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\gamma^a \, \gamma^b + \gamma^b \, \gamma^a = 2 \, \eta^{ab}.
\end{equation}
Any set of 4 matrices which obeys this relation can be used in equation (1) above (usual Dirac representation, Weyl representation, Majorana representation, etc).  All representations are related by an unitary transformation :
\begin{align}\tag{3}
\tilde{\gamma}^a &= U \, \gamma^a U^{\dagger}, \\[12pt]
\tilde{\Psi} &= U \, \Psi. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Now, suppose that the representation becomes a ***local symetry*** of the Dirac equation ; $U \Rightarrow U(x)$.  We then need to change the partial derivative :
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\partial_a \Rightarrow D_a \equiv \partial_a + i C_a(x),
\end{equation}
where $C_a(x)$ is a new gauge field.

I did not pursued further that idea by lack of time.  But I would like to know if this idea has been explored by someone else (surrely it was already studied before !).

So what it gives ?  What kind of interaction gauge field ?  Is there any mathematical problem with this ?

---

**EDIT :** Just a few more comments :

The *Lorentz group* acting on the Dirac field is represented by $SL(4, \mathbb{C})$, and its elements aren't all unitary matrices :  the rotations are represented by unitary matrices, but not the pure Lorentz transformations.

Gauging the Lorentz group gives **gravitation** (this is well known and is a part of classical General relativity).  Then gauging the $\gamma$ representation will certainly interfere with the gravitation gauge field (veirbein and its spin connection), since some unitary matrices may represent some rotations (but not all unitary matrices !).

I don't think that the group of transformations that are changing the $\gamma$ representation is the same as the Lorentz group (i.e. $SL(4, \mathbb{C})$), but I may be wrong.

What is the full group that is defining the $\gamma$ representations ?  Does it really need to be unitary, i.e. $SU(4)$ ?  I suspect they are just similarity transformations, so any invertible 4 X 4 matrices may be good, not just unitary matrices.

In other words, is there a transformation of $SL(4, \mathbb{C})$ (from the Lorentz group) that may change the usual Dirac matrices to the Weyl matrices and to the Majorana matrices ?

Comment: This would be a gauge theory with gauge group the Lorentz group. The Lorentz group isn't compact which means technical complications so it might be that this hasn't been studied. Much work on gauge theory doesn't specify the gauge group, but I think it is the rule to assume that it is compact.

Comment: The Rarita-Schwinger field has a fermionic gauge symmetry. Perhaps considering that would be helpful. See for instance: https://books.google.be/books?id=KFUhAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA96&ots=vh0WtWM5rg&dq=rarita%20schwinger%20fermionic%20gauge%20symmetry&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question - gauge symmetries are defined *on the level of the Lagrangian*, and must be given by *transformations of the fields*. $\gamma\mapsto U\gamma U^\dagger$ is not a transformation of a field and hence not a prescription for a symmetry. In particular, you cannot gauge this symmetry because $\gamma^a$ *does not depend on spacetime to begin with*, so replacing $U$ by $U(x)$ does not make any sense. Also, the Lorentz group (or more precisely its universal cover) is $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})$, not $\mathrm{SL}(4,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, $SL(4, \mathbb{C})$ IS a representation of the Lorentz group, for the Dirac field.  $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ doesn't act of the Dirac field, which is a 4 components spinor.  Also, the $\gamma$ representation is a **global** symetry of the Dirac lagrangian (changing representation means that you do change the field representation itself, not just the $\gamma$'s).  It CAN be made a local symetry, exactly as for the global $U(1)$ phase symetry.  So it does make sense.

Comment: You are using non-standard terminology. The Dirac representation is a group homomorphism $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{C})\to\mathrm{GL}(4,\mathbb{C})$, but $\mathrm{SL}(4,\mathbb{C})$ is not "a representation of the Lorentz group". The transformation $\gamma\mapsto U\gamma U^\dagger$ is *not* a "symmetry" of the Lagrangian in the formal sense because symmetries must be given by *field transformations* and $\gamma$ is *not a field*, it is a constant. It's something you can do to the Lagrangian, but it is not a symmetry, and it does not make sense to speak of "gauging" it.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I don't agree.  In the lagrangian, you change the field with a matrix $U$ (mixing the spinor components).  To leave the lagrangian unchanged, you need to ask that $U$ also change the $\gamma$ matrices (then it's a change of representation).  This can be made *local*.  Then the $\gamma$'s becomes fields themselves.  This may all be related to gravity.

Comment: @Cham since you're still discussing this; is there something lacking about my answer below/ do you mean something else/ do you want me to expand on it?

Comment: @Gerben, your answer doesn't fit my question (or may be it's a generalization of it, I don't know).  The Dirac spinor I'm interested in isn't of the Rarita-Schwinger type (i.e. spinor with a coordinate index).  Also, my question is much about defining clearly the group of representations of the $\gamma$ matrices, and in what sense is it different from the Lorentz group.

Comment: The Rarita-Schwinger field has a fermionic gauge symmetry; which seemed to be what you were driving at. There is indeed a link with gravity as you suggested as this gives the gravitino; the supersymmetric partner of gravity in supergravity. The dirac field cannot have such a gauged symmetry as it fully gauges away spin-1/2 so nothing is left. If you are interested in the formal properties of $\gamma$ matrices in a group theoretic context: They form what is known as a Clifford algebra and you should look at that.

Comment: @Cham: what ACuriousMind means is that $U$ is not a symmetry transformation of $\gamma$. Upon a Lorentz transformation $\psi\to U\psi$, $\bar\psi\gamma_\mu\psi\to\Lambda_\mu^\nu \bar\psi\gamma_\nu\psi$ transform as 4-vector. But in itself, $\gamma_\mu$ is **not** a 4-vector (Lorentz transformations do not affect). Other than that, you are indeed gauging Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @Adam, yes I know all this.  I was considering the possibility to make the $\gamma$ as a part of a new gauge symetry, under their **arbitrary representation**.  But after thinking a bit more on this today, I realized that's it's really about gravity ! (plus maybe something more, I'm not sure yet).  If the $\gamma$ representation is made local, then the $\gamma$ must become dynamical fields, instead of simple constants (as ACuriousMind pointed out).  But then this ask to use the **vierbein** (tetrad) field contracted on them.  This implies *gravity*.  However, ... (see below)

Comment: However, ... the group of the $\gamma$ representation transformations is unitary (I don't know why), so it's not the Lorentz group.  It does includes the **rotations** (as the Lorentz group), but it also includes weird things like the *chiral transformation*, which of course is not part of the Lorentz group.  So "gauging" the $\gamma$ representation needs gravity (what the... !?), or conflict with it.  So I guess that one answer to my question above is "NO, because gravity takes the place" !

Comment: It's definitely an intriguing idea. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the Dirac representation of the Lorentz group is $(1/2,0) \oplus(0,1/2)$. And therefore the transformation matrix should be of the form $A \oplus (A^{-1})^\dagger$, where $A \in SL(2, \mathbb{C})$. Just from analyzing the dimensionality, it should actually be clear that it can't be $SL(4,\mathbb{C})$ or $GL(4,\mathbb{C})$ since both have way too many degrees of freedom. And yes, you can make arbitrary equivalence transformations. We usually don't do it because you lose $\gamma^{\mu \dagger} = \gamma^0 \gamma^\mu \gamma^0$.

Comment: Can you maybe go into more detail, how this is connected to gravity. I see a slight connection with $\lbrace \gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu \rbrace = 2 \eta^{\mu \nu} \longrightarrow \lbrace \gamma^\mu (x), \gamma^\nu (x) \rbrace = 2 g^{\mu \nu}(x)$ but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, I think the Rarita Schwinger field (spin 3/2) has exactly the gauge symmetry you want:
https://books.google.be/books?id=KFUhAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA96&ots=vh0WtWM5rg&dq=rarita%20schwinger%20fermionic%20gauge%20symmetry&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q&f=false
This gauge symmetry removes the spin 1/2 component of the field so only the spin 3/2 part is left.
Now if you did the same gauging to the spin 1/2 field, you would gauge the entire spin 1/2 field away, the object would be made entirely out of nonphysical arbitrary gauge-stuff; I think.

Answer (score -2):

Imposing local gauge symmetry on the Dirac equation produces the electromagnetic field interacting with it.

See

http://www.physics.rutgers.edu/~steves/613/lectures/Lec06.pdf

Before any down voting please see my comments below. The question was not about we whether Dirac's equation can be used to represent a spin 3/2 or higher fermion, though you could interpret it that way, and his example simply added a vector field as the gauge field. There is then no choice and it has to be electromagnetism. Weyl and Majorana fields are also consistent. See Peskin.  Btw, the spin 3/2 Rarita Schwinger field I understand has problems, though I am not an expert on it.

If this is totally off the mark, just explain please.

Comment: Sorry I had to down-vote your answer.  The EM gauge field is related to the $U(1)$ group, wich commutes with all the $\gamma$ matrices.  It isn't related to the $\gamma$ representations at all.

Comment: Understand. But it seems to introduce that interaction in Diracs equation. See the reference. You still have U(1) from the EM equations, but this gauge symmetry creates the interaction term in Dirac

Comment: Yes, the $U(1)$ local invariance introduces the EM field into the Dirac equation.  This is very well known and is the best (i.e. simplest) example of how to introduce gauge fields into physics.  But it isn't related to the question.

Comment: No? If you make your C to be A, what is the difference?

Comment: Plus see also the Weyl equation and Majorana fermions derived from Dirac and Lorentz invariance in http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/four.pdf.    It is well known also.